How to slow down Ethernet Card in Windows
Is there some way to slow down the Ethernet card in Windows? I have a 1GB/s card and I want to slow it down to a given speed, for example to 5MB/s.
I know I can easily slow down the card to 100MB/s or to 10MB/s including Half/Full duplex control in Control Panel by changing the network card properties.
But I need to have greater speed control.
So far I can only imagine that I would use some kind of router with advance QoS, but I wonder if this can be achieved by changing settings or using special software directly on the target windows host/machine.

Either go for setting the speed as described, put in a cable that can't handle faster speeds (will probably limit you to 100mbps) or use a program such as NetLimiter. Technically, a router may also be able to limit the bandwidth, but htat is going to be harder to setup and maintain. With Netlimiter, you can at least control the speed per application.

QOS has nothing to do with this. That is not a bandwidth throttle. Either NetLimiter (or similar application) on the PC itself or bandwidth throttle on the router side (if connection is directly to router) or switch (if connection goes to a switch). Note that most SOHO routers/switches don't have bandwidth throttle features.

Adding a use case might be helpful. For example, for testing website performance there are default network throttle settings under chrome's developer tools. Alternatively, windows has a powershell cmdlet called "New-NetQOSPolicy" that can throttle bandwith. Example: New-NetQOSPolicy -Name ‘HTTPS’ -IPPort 443 -IPProtocol TCP -ThrottleRateActionBitsPerSecond 500KB. This will throttle all https traffic (port 443) to a max of 500KB.

need to test,  but at first glance the most interesting answer seems to be from @Silbee, also NetLimiter https://www.netlimiter.com/ looks promising.

The REASON you want/need this will help us better help you, because depending on your actual needs, the answer may vary widely. Please share with us the reason(s) you are trying to do this.

In our project we have to do test in stress situation including the situation when internet, and intranet will slow down in any possible cases.
